# VPN personal tunnel/bridge

Tags: vpn, pptp

At our office some of our staff has VPN accounts to another network. Our problem is that each person needs to maintain their own vpn setup and due to our non-perfect ISP they constantly get the Windows re-dial popup.

I would therefore like to know if there is a way for us to maintain the connections on our central server? And then either use some advanced routing so that each person is connected with their personal login on the other network, or connects to vpn on our local server with their normal username and password and then they are connected to the other network through that connection.

Answer (score 0):

More information  on your topology would be good here.

That said, OpenVPN will automatically reconnect when it's been disconnected. If the disconnection is brief, most client applications will freeze for a bit, then resume when the tunnel comes back up.

Comment: The other network is an MS PPTP, and since that is not under our control there is little I can do about that. What other topology would you like to know?

Comment: I can't figure out why each client needs their own VPN connection for authentication. Can you just bridge the two networks at the server level? What type of network services are you trying to use?

Comment: That is a requirement from the other network. And not everyone in our office has access, so would not be good to just bridge the two networks

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use pptp with a Linux server/router, have a look at poptop. In fact, look at these articles here:

http://blog.doylenet.net/?p=17

http://poptop.sourceforge.net/dox/replacing-windows-pptp-with-linux-howto.phtml

The windows PPTP client should auto-reconnect as necessary, and I imagine the Linux and OSX pptp clients do the same.

If you're not using a Linux router with poptop for your VPN, then you might want to consider it.

Comment: As far as I can see, that will only give me a VPN server, it wont solve any of the two issues I wrote about? Is there a way to somehow redirect the traffic to the vpn server to the other network under peoples own account on the other network?

Comment: @Cine: "redirect traffic to the other network under people's own account on the other network" -- this doesn't make sense. Presumably there's something specific that you're trying to accomplish, but the technology must not work the way you think it does.